# How to invoke @Click (Python) but also pass in other parameters that aren't from Click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, click, command-line-interface

I have a python script that I am trying to invoke from bash/shell/cli. I have used a module called 'Click' before; however, I don't think it's possible to both pass in parameters using 'Click' AND passing in non-click parameters (such as a dictionary or list).  Is there a way I can still pass in the non-click parameter? (Below is my attempt at trying to accomplish this:)

```
response_dict = json.loads(response.text)

@click.command()
@click.argument("md5hash_passed")

def find_pr_id (response, md5hash_passed):
   values = response["values"]
   for item in values:
      item_id = item["id"]
      fromref = item["fromRef"]
      md5_hash = fromref["latestCommit"]
      branch_name = fromref["displayId"]
      if md5_hash == md5hash_passed:
         return item_id

find_pr_id(response_dict)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't run find_pr_id directly, try this:

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    ctx.obj = json.loads(response.text)

@cli.command()
@click.pass_obj
@click.argument("md5hash_passed")
def find_pr_id (request, md5hash_passed):
    values = request["values"]
    for item in values:
        item_id = item["id"]
        fromref = item["fromRef"]
        md5_hash = fromref["latestCommit"]
        branch_name = fromref["displayId"]
        if md5_hash == md5hash_passed:
            return item_id

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

run with :

```
python test.py find-pr-id 123
```

Comment: (BTW): 

```find-pr-id``` is considered a "object" right?

Comment: `ctx.obj` is the object, I renamed to `request` in function `find_pr_id`.

Comment: Oh I know :)  I was just wondering how to properly reference it. (Thanks again)